# Fetching variable number of rows from ms access database based on vaules found on another table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, oracle-xe, rownum

I've spent my whole day trying to come up with a solution for this problem, but I still have no clue:

I have in one table **users** the following fields:

- id
- name
- city_id
- score

and in another table **city** two fields:

- id
- users_number

What I have to do is to get the top rows from the **users** table as specified by the users_number field in **city** but first, ordering the fetched rows by score. The users quantity is far larger than the value specified by users_number.

My question is:

is there any possibility to select from the table **users** where criteria is number of rows in table **city**?

thank you

Comment: You've tagged this for Access and for Oracle.  Are you trying to come up with a single query that works for both?  Optimized queries for each?  Or did you really mean to tag the question for either one or the other database but not both?

Comment: I was initially testing this using Access, but as I regarded it as a difficult query, thought it could be better to test it under Oracle, which might support more advanced SQL features. So, it is ok if it comes for either oracle or Access.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for MS Access:

```
SELECT t.ID, (
   SELECT Count(ID) 
   FROM users s 
   WHERE s.ID<=t.ID And s.city_id=t.city_id) AS Expr1
FROM users AS t
INNER JOIN City c
ON t.city_id = c.ID
WHERE (
    SELECT Count(ID) 
    FROM users s 
    WHERE s.ID<=t.ID And s.city_id=t.city_id)<=c.users_number
ORDER BY t.ID
```

Result:

```
id  city_id Expr1
1       1       1
2       1       2 
-----------------------------
5       2       1
6       2       2
7       2       3
-----------------------------
9       3       1
```

Where ID is user ID and Expr1 is an order.

Input

Users

```
id  name    city_id 
1   a       1   
2   b       1   
3   c       1   
4   d       1   
5   e       2   
6   a       2   
7   b       2   
8   c       2   
9   d       3   
10  e       3
```

City

```
id  users_number
1   2
2   3
3   1
```

Comment: Well, I executed this query with no satisfactory results. It does not fetches the desired number of rows per city. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer in T-SQL should that be of any help in figuring it out for Access?

```
declare @users table 
(
    id int primary key clustered
    , name nvarchar(64)
    , city_id int 
    , score int
)
declare @city table (
    id int primary key clustered
    , name nvarchar(64)
    , users_number int
)

insert @city
      select 1, 'San Fran', 2
union select 2, 'NY', 5

insert @users
      select 1, 'Steve Fields', 1, 10
union select 2, 'Sarah Felcher', 1, 20
union select 3, 'Nick Yarnton', 2, 12
union select 4, 'Nigel Yardsman', 2, 12
union select 5, 'Nicki Yakatou', 2, 13
union select 6, 'Nicola Yates', 2, 23
union select 7, 'Steph Freeman', 1, 15
union select 8, 'Ned Yount', 2, 18
union select 9, 'Neil Yorke', 2, 1

select *
from @city c
left outer join 
(
    select id, name, city_id, score
    , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by city_id order by score desc) r
    from @users
) u
on c.id = u.city_id
where c.users_number >= u.r
order by c.id, u.score desc
```